# What are all countries can visit using Schengen business visa?

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, business-travel

I got my first visa as Schengen business visa for Germany for two weeks with multiple entries. Using this visa, what are all countries I can visit near by Hamburg?

I'm travelling on next week, please suggest some countries and places to visit for this Feb month. This is my first visa and am not aware about this visa much. So please provide inputs

Comment: You applied for a visa without understanding how it works?

Answer (score 3):

With your first entry, you should travel as you described it in your visa application. You can change where you transit within the Schengen area without problem.

After the first visit, if there is time left on the multiple-entry visa, one can visit other Schengen countries.

Comment: after entered Hamburg, I can go other Schengen countries using this business visa? shall i go Paris and Amserdam using this visa?

Comment: You have two weeks, multiple entry. What did you write in your application? Hamburg, Paris, Amsterdam? Or just Hamburg?